# Rank using different type columns in pandas dataframe with both ascending and descending alternatives for each column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a way to determine the rank using multiple columns in a pandas dataframe. These columns can contribute in different orders i.e. ascending or descending and can have different types i.e. int or str.

I've tried to put the column data in a tuple and then rank them using the rank method. However, this only provides the rank in either ascending or descending order for both columns.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'String':['a','a','a','a','b'],'Integer':[1,2,3,3,1]})
df['tup'] = df.apply(tuple,axis=1)
# For both columns taken into account in ascending order
df['rank'] = df['tup'].rank() 
# For both columns taken into account in descending order
df['rank'] = df['tup'].rank(ascending=False)
```

I expect the output to be the one below with String taken into account as ascending and Integer as descending

```py
# Expected 
  String  Integer     tup  rank
0      a        1  (a, 1)   4.0
1      a        2  (a, 2)   3.0
2      a        3  (a, 3)   1.5
3      a        3  (a, 3)   1.5
4      b        1  (b, 1)   5.0
```

but instead it is for both columns taken into account as ascending

```py
# Actual
  String  Integer     tup  rank
0      a        1  (a, 1)   1.0
1      a        2  (a, 2)   2.0
2      a        3  (a, 3)   3.5
3      a        3  (a, 3)   3.5
4      b        1  (b, 1)   5.0
```

Comment: Would you like to rank first by string, followed by integer?

Comment: Yes in this example. But I am also interested in a generic way to rank different types in different orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach. You can tweak `ascending` as you wish to order the columns (or as many as columns as you wish) however you prefer:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'String':['a','a','a','a','b'],'Integer':[1,2,3,3,1]})
df = df.sort_values(['String','Integer'], ascending=[True, False])
df['rank'] = np.arange(len(df)) + 1
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['String', 'Integer'])['rank'].transform('mean')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  String  Integer  rank
2      a        3   1.5
3      a        3   1.5
1      a        2   3.0
0      a        1   4.0
4      b        1   5.0
```

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136881/compute-rank-average-for-multiple-columns-manually) based on this to generalize the idea of ranking multiple types of columns, you can check it to give credit to the people who worked out the answer aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by calculating ranks of both columns individually and then putting the ranks in a tuple. Then, I can use the rank method on that tuple.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'String':['a','a','a','a','b'],'Integer':[1,2,3,3,1]})
df['tup'] = tuple(zip(df['String'].rank(ascending=True), df['Integer'].rank(ascending=False)))
df['rank'] = df['tup'].rank()
```

The output is given below-

```py
  String  Integer         tup  rank
0      a        1  (2.5, 4.5)   4.0
1      a        2  (2.5, 3.0)   3.0
2      a        3  (2.5, 1.5)   1.5
3      a        3  (2.5, 1.5)   1.5
4      b        1  (5.0, 4.5)   5.0
```

Comment: Can remove a step by adding `df['rank'] = (df['String'].rank(ascending=True) + df['Integer'].rank(ascending=False)).rank()`

Comment: No, rank of tuple of (2,8) is higher than (3,1)

Comment: It should be also noted, that we're trying to solve the `rank` problem when using strings and integers, if you had full words as string, this solution would not prove to be a general solution for the issue.

Comment: @CeliusStingher Could you give an example dataframe ?

Comment: This is not my answer, check my answer for the example dataframe and output.