# Compute rank average for multiple columns manually

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I am looking for a way to generate a ranking with average as method based on multiple columns where one contains strings and the other integers (could be easily more than 2 columns, but I'm limiting to 2 for an easier example).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'String':['a','a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c'],'Integer':[1,2,3,3,1,3,6,4,4,4]})
print(df)
  String  Integer
0      a        1
1      a        2
2      a        3
3      a        3
4      b        1
5      b        3
6      c        6
7      c        4
8      c        4
9      c        4
```

The idea is to be able to create ranking that ranks each row by String in descending order and integer in ascending order, this would be the output:

```
    Rank String  Integer
0      2      c        4           
1      2      c        4         
2      2      c        4          
3      4      c        6          
4      5      b        1          
5      6      b        3         
6      7      a        1            
7      8      a        2            
8    9.5      a        3            
9    9.5      a        3
```

So far this is what I manage to do, but I'm having trouble on how to generate the 'average' when a rank is shared.

```
df['concat_values'] = df['String'] + df['Integer'].astype(str)  
df = df.sort_values(['String','Integer'],ascending=[False,True])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).reset_index()
df['repeated'] = df.groupby('concat_values')['concat_values'].transform('count')
df['pre_rank'] = df['index'] + 1
df = df.sort_values('pre_rank')
df = df.drop('index',axis=1)
print(df)
  String  Integer concat_values  repeated  pre_rank
0      c        4            c4         3         1
1      c        4            c4         3         2
2      c        4            c4         3         3
3      c        6            c6         1         4
4      b        1            b1         1         5
5      b        3            b3         1         6
6      a        1            a1         1         7
7      a        2            a2         1         8
8      a        3            a3         2         9
9      a        3            a3         2        10
```

I thought of using some filtering or formula so that when the column `repeated` takes a value higher than one, the `pre_rank` gets a function applied that returns the average, but that function can't be generalized for all rows, it'll work for the first one, but it will yield a higher value for the second one (because `pre_rank` has a higher value now). I believe I am just missing the final step towards getting it done, but can't work it out. Thanks!

Comment: Why the rank for `c` is 2 instead of 1 or 3?

Comment: Because c4 is repeated for rank 1,2,3. Using method = average assigns each row the same rank (an average of the ranks for the values) therefore, c4 will have rank 2 = ((1+2+3)/2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My method:

```
df = df.sort_values(['String','Integer'], ascending=[False, True])
df['rank'] = np.arange(len(df)) + 1
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['String', 'Integer'])['rank'].transform('mean')
```

Output:

```
  String  Integer  rank
7      c        4   2.0
8      c        4   2.0
9      c        4   2.0
6      c        6   4.0
4      b        1   5.0
5      b        3   6.0
0      a        1   7.0
1      a        2   8.0
2      a        3   9.5
3      a        3   9.5
```

Comment: This is exactly how I did it... except `range(1, len(df) + 1)` (-:

Answer (score 5):

#### `sort` + `ngroup` + `rank`.

Requires you to specify `sort=False` within the groupby so the `ngroup` labels are generated in the the order you sort.

```
df = df.sort_values(['String', 'Integer'], ascending=[False, True])
df['rank'] = df.groupby(['String', 'Integer'], sort=False).ngroup().rank()
```

---

```
  String  Integer  rank
7      c        4   2.0
8      c        4   2.0
9      c        4   2.0
6      c        6   4.0
4      b        1   5.0
5      b        3   6.0
0      a        1   7.0
1      a        2   8.0
2      a        3   9.5
3      a        3   9.5
```

Comment: Great use of `ngroup`